# Как зафиксировать скролл, при добавлении новых блоков?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблемный [пример](https://codepen.io/vintalis/pen/BaKGyOL)

При нажатии на LOAD MORE если items(блок) переносится вниз, то происходит скролл до кнопки. Я хочу, что б при нажатии на кнопку не скролилось к ней, и доскроливать вручную. Как отменить скролл, библиотека используется `Isotope`

Грубый [пример](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/wBYbgN) который подходит, как тут

Comment: У меня в двух приведенных примеров нет никакого скрола. При нажатии кнопка прыгает вниз, во втором примере если много раз нажать то кнопка уходит за экран. Win10 Chrome 85.0.4183.121

Comment: в первом примере, когда  нажать load more и блок переносится на другую строку, сроллит в самый низ, а нужно что б на месте оставалось.Во втором примере я показал, что этого доскроливания в низ нету, если нажать load more

Comment: Что скролит? окно браузера на месте стоит

Comment: В первом примере, дважды нажми , что б блоки перенеслись на вторую строку, и если в экран браузера не вмещается, доскраливает в самый низ.Во втором примере, который мне подходит по реализации , такого нету

Comment: @Greg-- смотрел?)

Comment: Поставьте кнопку вверху и браузер не будет скроллить

Comment: При изменении высоты браузер скроллит до элемента на который нажали

Comment: На эту кнопку поставить свойство вверх?А можно как то поставить кнопку, что б фиксировалось на месте, если нажать на эту кнопку.И почему тогда во втором примере не скролится, может все таки это связано с библиотекой Izotope , как ты думаешь?

Comment: Мне тоже так показалось, но посмотрел демки изотопа и сделал форк кодпен демки, поставил кнопку вверху и перестало прыгать. Это самый быстрый фикс, я не нашел что именно прокручивает страницу

Comment: $("#load-more").click(function() {
    
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '300');  }); Я вот так сделал, скролит вверх страницы тоже не подходит, тупо не понимаю как пофиксить((Хотя б отменить действия срола вниз , вроде на словах понятно, но как реализовать

Comment: Мне кажется это не скрипт делает а браузер на изменение DOM, но тоже не факт, нужно демку изотопа упростить до второго варианта, тогда более понятно будет

Comment: Я без понятия, как кнопку по другому сделать, что б подгружало в isotop, видел примеры все так делают .Упрощенно без понятия как(

Comment: @Greg-- появилась идея, последнему элементу в контейнере задавать класс, и при нажатии на кнопку показать больше, будет скролить имено к ней, должно пройти, вопрос как последнему элементу при клике в jquery добавить класс,а потом удалить и снова добавить последнему